# No certificates match the selected hostname in Azure Functionapp

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure

I cant add ssl binding to my Azure Function. I have uploaded the certificat, but when i try to bind it to a custom domain name I get "No certificates match the selescted hostname" as shown in the picture

[No certificates match the selescted hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5zIJ.png)

Comment: In your picture, you've blanked out the hostname you're trying to match with the cert. That makes it a lot harder to help you. But it does look as though there may be another dot in the name, e.g. `dtstatic.SOMETHING.dynamictemplate.com`. If so, the text above the hostname clearly says that's not going to work.

Comment: It is like dtstatistics-xxxxx.dynamictemplate.com - so only one subname

Comment: You've reloaded the webpage after uploading the cert?

Comment: There may be some issue with the certificate itself. Could you include the public part in your post (click "edit" under the text, then paste in the PEM certificate file you got from wherever you purchased your certificate - not the private key, just the public part!)

Comment: The certificate works fine for other subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to Microsoft Support - This was the resolution.

There was some conflict in the backend web space

RESOLUTION:

We are able to resolve the SSL binding to custom domain issue after creating the same function app to another resource group. We have done the following steps to achieve SSL binding to custom domain.
1)  Deleted the function app
2)  Create the new function app with the same name 
3)  Uploaded the private certificate into the function app
4)  Added custom domain into function app.
5)   Able to bind the SSL certificate to the custom domain.